# PICAXE 8 Pin Proto Kit

Tags: picaxe

I just soldered together the PICAXE 8 Pin Proto Kit, and I have a feeling there is one part missing.

Here are the images for the kit:

[image]

[image]

The part that I think is missing is the white component in the first picture and the blue component in the second image.

However, the list of components in the document that came with the kit says:

```
Contents:

    PCB     Protoboard PCB
    R1      10k resistor
    R2      22k resistor
    C1      100nf polyester capacitor
    H1      3pin header and jumper link
    CT1     stereo download socket
    BC      Battery Clip
    IC1     8 pin IC socket
```

The spot on the PCB corresponding to the missing component on the images is labeled "C1" to make things even more confusing.

(there is another place for "optional capacitor holes" where I soldered in the yellow 100nf capacitor, so I don't think the area labeled "C1" is for the capacitor)

**Questions:**

1. I would love to know what that part does (the white component in
   the first image and blue in the second).
2. Is it necessary or not?
3. Is it supposed to be there as per the list of components?

Comment: That this beginner-targeted kit supplies a "9v battery connector" for a device with a maximum voltage of 5.5v gives me a very low opinion of it.  Guess what was connected to the one that someone brought to our hackerspace?

Comment: Oh don't worry, I'm using a voltage regulator. Thx though!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They are both plastic film capacitors - the 100nF which should be placed on C1.

If by "extra capacitor holes" you are referring to the + and - holes at the bottom right, they are likely to be for an optional electroltyic to provide some bulk capacitance for the power input.

It's quite common for parts to be substituted in these kits, so you maybe have a ceramic 100nF instead of the mentioned plastic film capacitor (they will both work fine)
If yours looks a bit like one of these it's a ceramic:

[image]  [image] [image]

Comment: ah ok... Thx a ton! 

The capacitor that was provided is a small yellow one that has 104 stamped on the side. It doesn't look like the plastic film capacitors in the images.

I should still re-solder the capacitor that I soldered in earlier from the "extra capacitor holes" into the C1 right? (yes you are completely correct about the location of the extra capacitor holes).

Comment: Yes, definitely move it to C1. 104 means 10 + 4 0's in pF, so it's 100,000 pF = 100nF = 0.1uF. You can use something like a 100uF - 470uF or so in the +/- holes (this is optional - it will help if your supply has ripple/transients, but not so necessary with e.g a quiet supply like a battery)

Comment: oh ok. Just finished re-soldering =) Great to know the labeling system and the capacitor to use to smooth out current too. thx so much!

Comment: No problem, glad to help - it just occurred to me that yours may actually be a ceramic capacitor if it looks different (it will be smaller and look like the pictures I added) One last thing - make sure if you add an electrolytic you put it the right way round as they are polarised. The longer lead should be the positive and the negative side will almost always have a stripe. See [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electrolytic_capacitor#Polarity)

Comment: Right, I remember now that the circular (electrolytic) capacitors have that gray strip on the side that tells the polarity. Btw, I scratched the capacitor a little bit (looks cosmetic to me, but the capacitor itself is really small) when I was pulling it out with pliers (I haven't gotten a proper solder-remover yet). Should I be worried about it do you think? Thanks again!

Comment: Should hopefully be okay if you didn't squeeze too hard, a scratch on outside won't harm it. The only way it would damage anything is if it was shorted - to be sure test for continuity (very low resistance) between the leads (it shouldn't have any)